Fill a website Form using C# Desktop Application
I am trying to fill a website form using C# Desktop Application, I am using the following form as an example -
https://formsmarts.com/html-form-example
I have written the following code -
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            // Initialize Chrome WebDriver
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

            // Navigate to the form URL
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://formsmarts.com/html-form-example");

            // Find input fields by their IDs and fill them with desired values
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("u_HbM_4607")).SendKeys("John");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("u_HbM_338354")).SendKeys("Doe");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("u_HbM_4608")).SendKeys("johndoe@example.com");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("u_HbM_338367")).SendKeys("Website Feedback");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("u_HbM_4609")).SendKeys("Everything Rocks!!!");

            // Submit the form
            //driver.FindElement(By.Id("u_CU_221828")).Click();

            // Close the browser
            //driver.Quit();
        }

I am getting the following exception -
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#u_HbM_4607"}


at
driver.FindElement(By.Id("u_HbM_4607")).SendKeys("John");

This is where I am copying the ID field -
<input name="u_k0J_4607" id="u_k0J_4607" type="text" value="" class=" u-full-width" placeholder="Your first name" aria-required="true">

From here, Redirect to page, pre-filling form fields
I got to know that we can also send URL parameters to fill the fields, from the following answer
Are you just testing with an aspx page, or is the online approval form an aspx page?

You can try adding URL parameters to a GET request instead of POST.

http://www.amazon.co.uk/exec/obidos/search-handle-form?field-keywords=Harry+Potter

but how do I create this URL?
I researched and found the format from here - https://helpx.adobe.com/in/sign/adv-user/web-form/url-parameters.html
But how do I find the parameter names of this URL- https://formsmarts.com/html-form-example

Which line in the code shown is producing that exception?  I don't see the selector #u_CU_221823 used anywhere in the code shown.

@David Sorry, edited the question no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#u_HbM_4607

The fact that those selectors are different suggests perhaps a mistake in the debugging somewhere.  Though it's also worth noting that neither of the id values shown are present on the page when I examine it.  These id values appear to be dynamically generated on the target page, so hard-coding them as selectors is unlikely to work.  You may need to identify the element(s) in a different way.  Site scraping is an exercise in reverse-engineering, and some sites don't make it easy.

Notice how, in the ongoing edits to your question, you keep changing the id value.  If the id value keeps changing then it's being dynamically generated by the server and isn't a reliable selector.
There are a variety of ways to select an element on the page.  Some are more complex than others.  In this particular case the element itself may still have a unique enough attribute to be singled out.  Just for testing, I'd start with using that placeholder value.  Other inputs on the page are unlikely to share that same value.
Something like this:
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[placeholder='Your first name']")).SendKeys("John");


Edit in response to comments below:
It bears repeating a comment I made on the question above...

Site scraping is an exercise in reverse-engineering

You can't just keep making assumptions.  Examine the page in the DOM explorer, navigate to the element, and you'll find that it's inside an iframe.  Which makes it part of that document instead.
This looks potentially helpful.  I'm not entirely sold on the waiting part, and certainly wouldn't wait more than a second or so if necessary, but sometimes site scraping is like that.
Ideally waiting wouldn't use Thread.Sleep(1000) and would instead use await Task.Delay(1000), which would involve making this button click handler async.  It's up to you on that part, really.
More importantly is referencing the iframe document.  For example:
var frame = driver.Instance.FindElement(By.CssSelector("iframe.fs_embed"));
driver.Instance.SwitchTo().Frame(frame);
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[placeholder='Your first name']")).SendKeys("John");

Note that much of the above is untested code pieced together from other online sources.  You may need to debug and tinker with it a bit.  But the overall point is that you would need to:

Identify the iframe.
Switch to that document.
Find the element in the document.

It's also possible that you could manually grab the URL of the iframe from the page source and use that as the URL in your site scraping in the first place.  I don't know if the target site has anything preventing that from working.  Sometimes they do, sometimes they don't.  Site scraping is an exercise in reverse-engineering.

It still says, 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"input[placeholder='Your first name']"}

@Anonymous that was just an example, of course you need to replace placehilder='...' by some meaningful value in that HTML. We have no clue about the URL that you want to grab these information from. I just guess there is some attribute on the desired HTML-elements (beside the generated id) which stays constant and is unique.

Your First Name is the actual value of the placeholder. I checked from inspect element.

@Anonymous: I've updated the answer.  Look carefully at the DOM structure you're scraping.  It appears to be contained within an iframe.
